# Bootstrap labels intersected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have multiple `<span>` elements with bootstrap label style, and I get this:

[image: Image with problem.]

How to solve this problem?

update: (added snippet)

```css
.label {
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    display: inline;
    padding: .2em .6em .3em;
    font-size: 75%; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    line-height: 1; 
    color: #fff; 
    text-align: center; 
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: baseline; 
    border-radius: .25em;
}
```

```html
<span class="label">text</span>
```

Comment: please add your html and css codes, it's about css

Comment: @AlekseySergeev where problem?

Comment: @sglazkov http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2HTu.png

Comment: @AlekseySergeev can you give html demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<style type="text/css">
.label {
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    display: inline;
    padding: .2em .6em .3em;
    font-size: 75%; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    line-height: 1; 
    color: #fff; 
    text-align: center; 
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: baseline; 
    border-radius: .25em;
    margin: 4px;
    float: left;
}
</style>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <span class="label">2016-01-25</span>
  <span class="label">2016-01-01</span>
  <span class="label">2016-01-5</span>
  <span class="label">2016-02-01</span>
  <span class="label">2016-01-25</span>
  <span class="label">2016-01-25</span>
  <span class="label">2016-01-25</span>
  <span class="label">2016-01-25</span>
</div>
```

Comment: yep, thanks, set margin to 2px, and it looks great :)

Comment: @AlekseySergeev your wellcome, if you just have problem with the float, just put `<div class="clearfix"></div>` at the bottom of your div. ;)